# Pass Mapping value to Session Email Task

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have 2 source. Oracle and SQL Server. I need to extract CustomerID from both and match. I need 2 outputs.

1. Number of CustomerID from Oracle
2. Number of CustomerID matching between Oracle and SQL Server.

Then, generate report and send it through mail to user.

1. Source - Oracle
   Source - MS SQL
2. Joiner (Detail outer join with oracle)
3. Router
   Group 1: CustomerID(Oracle) is not null and CustomerID(SQL Server) is null
   Group 2: CustomerID from both not null
4. AGG transformation after both group to get count
5. Union to merge it
6. Load into target file

Now I will have to use Shell script to prepare mail and send it to user.

Is there way we can do it simple? like assigning count to workflow variable and then use it in Email task?

Answer (score 0):

goto workflow:

1. open the session task and navigate to components tab
2. edit on sucess email and set type t0 non-reusable
3. click on edit button in value
4. click on edit button next to email text
5. enter "%l" . this will get the count of records and send to you in the email body.